# The Mean Time Between Failure (MTBF) Quantity

Tags: measurement, timing, reliability

It is the amount of time a system is operational i.e. MTTF plus the amount of time to repair it MTTR.
I am considering repairable systems only.

I know that it helps in scheduling maintenance, safety involved, material management and etc.

MTBF = Number of operational hours ÷ Number of failures
Or
MTBF = MTTR + MTTF

The units are

MTTR is in hrs./repair

MTTF is in hrs./failure

MTBF is in hrs./(failure + repair)

My question is a higher MTBF better?

Not necessarily.

The larger MTTF the better and conversely the smaller MTTR the better.
Although both MTTR and MTTF are directly proportional to MTBF.

So, knowing ONLY MTBF doesn't describe the availability/reliability of the system.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right although the vast majority of folk don't seem to consider MTTR as the big spoiler when using MTBF (rather than using the more useful MTTF value).

Comment: @Andy aka I elaborated more to make my point more clearer.

Comment: Why are you adding "mean time to repair" to your MTBF definition? Wouldn't this be the same as adding the "mean down time" (MDT) from [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures), therefore skewing the metric to just become a "mean time between restarts"?

Comment: I don't think you needed to. This question about MTBF is one that is well-known amongst those studying reliability.

Comment: @VicenteCunha  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Seongwoo-Woo/publication/334205633/figure/fig5/AS:778549820682240@1562632150490/A-schematic-diagram-of-MTTF-MTTR-and-MTBF.ppm and https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThwvOvdNtmO7jUbsXXzyWmHgUPm9lsPyfYJYvnpi01cLcF1VPDosps0otY5wa_UjF0Hh0&usqp=CAU - the lack of agreement between wiki and other sources make this a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka, indeed. Seems like wikipedia defines MTBF more like a "mean up-time" quantity, which would match the definition of MTTF in your first link.

Comment: @VicenteCunha there doesn't appear to be a definitive source about this. I was taught at college that MTBF = MTTF + MTTR but, that's just me. Maybe it's time for someone to define this once and for all time.

Comment: @Andyaka and I have discussed this before, but as you point out, the idea that you can improve MTBF by closing the repair shop is delightfully absurd. If using it as a metric, define Availability as MTTF/(MTTF + MTTR) = MTTF/MTBF and make that a key metric too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is entirely application dependent. In some cases you expect that the failure will occur rather frequently so you minimize the time to repair. For example, the air filter in a jeep engine.

In other applications the MTBF is all that really matters. You can accept a very high MTTR because you never intend to repair the equipment. For example, intercontinental ballistic missiles.

Comment: I believe the industry has moved away from MTBF as a defining parameter for reliability.  Reliability folks use the term FIT - Failures in Time, for a component or assembly.

Comment: @SteveSh Perhaps, but the OP asked specifically about MTBF. And the examples I mentioned are not typical "industry" examples.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your questions, it's important to define the abbreviations.  These mean something to Reliability, Maintainability, and Safety (RMS) engineers, but are often assumed to mean something else by others.  RMS engineers define these as follows:

- MTTF is the mean time to failure and is the basic reliability metric for NON-repairable items.
- MTBF is the mean time between failures and is the basic reliability metric for repairable items.
- MTTR is the mean time to repair and is the basic maintainability metric for repairable items.

Since you are considering repairable systems only, MTTF is irrelevant.

MTBF is not the sum of MTTF and MTTR.  It is the mean of the s-distribution of failure times (interarrival times in queuing theory parlance) for a system.  For historical reasons which were practical in the days of the slide rule, RMS engineers generally assume failure times are exponentially distributed.  Thus, MTBF represents the time by which 63.2% of all failures will occur.  However, if failure times are not exponentially distributed, the percentage of failures occurring by the MTBF may be different.  For example, if failure times are normally distributed, this is 50%.

To answer your first question, "Is a higher MTBF better?"  The answer is yes, under the strong assumption of exponentially distributed failures times.  Your conclusion that it depends is correct, your reasoning is not.  It depends because the failure times my not follow the same statistical distribution.

To answer your second question, "Knowing ONLY MTBF doesn't describe the availability/reliability of the system?" With regards to availability [A(t)], a basic measure of A(t) can be calculated as:

```
 A(t) = MTBF / (MTBF + MTTR)
```

From this you can see that only MTBF tells you very little about system A(t).

With regards to system reliability [R(t)], MTBF may tell you something about the reliability.  Under the strong assumption of exponentially distributed failure times, the reliability can be calculated as:

```
 R(t) = EXP(-t / MTBF)
```

Thus, you can see that MTBF is a proxy for reliability.  However, if we drop the assumption of exponentially distributed failure times, the MTBF will tell you nothing about reliability.

Under the exponentially distributed assumption, the hazard rate is the inverse of the MTBF.  It is typical to express MTBF as hours/failure and the hazard rate as failures/million hours.  A failure in time (FIT) is a hazard rate expressed as failures/billion hours and is typical in the semiconductor industry, but most use failures/million hours.

Answer (score 1):

There are important enough things missing from your analysis that it isn't particularly useful.

The tool that many Quality systems tend to hang their analysis of such errors on is **"Failure Mode and Effects Analysis", or FMEA** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_mode_and_effects_analysis, though that page uses slightly different notation)

The biggest problem with your analysis is that there's no context for what a failure means to the scenario.  In FMEA, this is worked into the equation.  You generate a Risk Priority Number (RPN) for each failure mode you can anticipate (or a new failure mode that comes up, depending on where you are in the life cycle) by generating scores for Severity (S), Occurrence (O), and Detectability (D), and multiplying those together.  The higher the resulting number, the higher the priority for a given failure mode.

So, if an error has severe ramifications (High S), but it's easy to detect when the failure is about to occur and deal with it (D), or if it only happens extremely rarely (low O), that might not be a bad RPN. Some people also look at the Criticality number (S*O).

An example of an FMEA table from https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter-Struss-2/publication/220838473/figure/fig4/AS:668343161876497@1536356835983/An-example-of-FMEA-table.png  is below:

[image]
Of course, sometimes the RPN that results is misleading, so nobody considers the RPN as carved in stone, but it makes sure that the important conversations happen.

For your scenario, MTTR might work itself in to the S number, as might the cost of repair/replace.  Now, if the replacement part is cheap, and you have extras around, you don't care, it's dead nuts apparent that the failure is about to occur (or is occurring) and you can swap the part out in time easily, with no damage to a process, the numbers your analysis is generating just don't match up to the real world impact.

From my perspective, the severity of having a process go down is often far more impactful that the resources that go into repair, but I'm sure there are some worlds where this isn't the case.